# click event working only for the first time jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

Below code work for the first time after refreshing the page. But when I try to click again it doesn't work.

After clicking on the element it goes to the next page (detail page) and when it come back, the click event doesn't work.

```
getNewsCategoryloop: function(dataMap){
    var _this = this;
    var text;

    text  = "<div id=\"repeat_get_list_of_category\">";
    for(key in dataMap) {
        text += '<div class="gallery_wrap col-2">\
                    <div class="gallery_view full_image" id="cat'+key+'">\
                        <img src="assets/img/news/athletics_img.jpg" alt="athletics">\
                        <span class="gallery_title">'+ (dataMap[key].field_saf == null ? 'no title' : dataMap[key].field_saf) +'</span>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';
                $(document).on('click', "#cat"+key, function(){
                    _this.getNewsbyCategoryName("#cat"+key);
                })
    }
 text+= "</div>";
 $("#getListOfNewsCategorylist").html(text);            
},
```

Comment: Any output in the developer consol in your browser?

Comment: Show us your full code so that it will clear about your problem.

Comment: no error in console. it doesn't even reach to that section `onclick`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this code:-

```
$(document).on('click', "#cat"+key, function(){
  _this.getNewsbyCategoryName("#cat"+key);
})
```

Outside of the whole function itself and change it like below:-

```
$(document).on('click', ".gallery_view", function(){
  app.getNewsbyCategoryName($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

So code need to be:-

```
getNewsCategoryloop: function(dataMap){
    var _this = this;
    var text;

    text  = "<div id=\"repeat_get_list_of_category\">";
    for(key in dataMap) {
        text += '<div class="gallery_wrap col-2">\
                    <div class="gallery_view full_image" id="cat'+key+'">\
                        <img src="assets/img/news/athletics_img.jpg" alt="athletics">\
                        <span class="gallery_title">'+ (dataMap[key].field_saf == null ? 'no title' : dataMap[key].field_saf) +'</span>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';

    }
    text+= "</div>";
    $("#getListOfNewsCategorylist").html(text);         
};
$(document).on('click', ".gallery_view", function(){
   app.getNewsbyCategoryName($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: with some minor modification in your code, it actually worked :). Thanks alot. what I modified is `$(this).getNewsbyCategoryName($(this).attr('id'));` to `app.getNewsbyCate......`

Comment: @Santosh  let me know it so that i can edit my answer.